# Can't append thread to array

Tags: python, arrays, multithreading

So I want to save my threads in an array, like this:

```
threads = []
```

To add threads to this array, I create them and append them:

```
t = thread.start_new_thread(process_client, (client, address))
threads.append(t)
```

The problem happens when I try to join them:

```
for thread in threads:
    thread.join
```

The following error appears:

```
'int' object has no attribute 'join'
```

I know the problem here is that when I create the thread the variable `t` will get an integer that will be appended to the array, setting its type to integer. And when I try to apply the method `join()` in an integer I get an error. Do any of you guys have a solution to this casting problem?

I'm on python 2.7 btw

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`thread.start_new_thread` returns the thread identifier, not the tread itself. So you are actually appending the tread identifiers which are integers.

You could create and start a Thread object (for that you need to import Thread from threading) then you would have a reference to it

Ex:

```
t = Thread(target=your_target, args=your_args)
t.start()
threads.append(t)
```

Comment: Then how do i append the threads? Is there a way? Thanks in advance

Comment: I edited the answer with a skeleton code of what you want to do

Comment: It doesnt work... it returns "global name 'Thread' is not defined" . Do I need any special import? I currently have "import thread"

Comment: As I wrote in the answer you need to import Thread from threading like so: `from threading import Thread`

Comment: And also change the target and arguments to what you need

Comment: Nice is working. Also forgot to put the target= and args=